# Apache Camel Classloader for Websphere

Tags: apache-camel, classloader

I am using Apache Camel with websphere. We have had some classloader issues.
I understand that Camel provides a websphere classloader but I cannot find an example in how to use it.
 tried putting this in the apllicationContext.xml file
`<bean id="WebsphereResolver" class="org.apache.camel.impl.WebSpherePackageScanClassResolver" />`
but I got the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.camel.impl.WebSpherePackageScanClassResolver.<init>()
```

What is correct format?

Comment: Its out of the box. What version of Camel and WebSphere are you using? And what classloader issues do you have.

Comment: Our camel version is 2.12.0.redhat-610379 For websphere it is WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.0. We are having a problem with fasterxml. We are seeing the error:Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/Version;)V
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1363)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)

Comment: Why are you using Red Hat JBoss Fuse on WebSphere? Do you have a subscription? If so the Red Hat customer portal can quicker help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was we were using an old version of fasterxml as defined in our pom.xml. Once we updated the pom.xml to use a new version of fasterxml, the problem went away. The apachexml bean uses fasterxml if it is available, but it assumes you are using a recent version.